# What is an efficient algorithm for performing Manchester encoding in software?

Tags: encoding

What's an efficient way to do Manchester encoding in software?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote two [articles](http://nongreedy.ru/embedded/2012/10/07/manchester-code-for-dummies/) about software Manchester encoding and decoding - unfortunately main text is in Russian, but there are many pictures and ready [sources](https://github.com/mazko/Manchester-Code). If short, i used **gtest** + **gmock** to find the simplest working solution first, then i produced a real [example](http://nongreedy.ru/embedded/2012/10/07/manchester-code-real-world-example/) with two microcontrollers. Of course this is the simplest solution, you can use this as start point to produce more complex one, for example - add algorithms to try recover damaged Manchester code e.t.c.

Comment: articles and example links return 404 errors